# telnet on Windows 8: even after installing still an unknown command

Tags: windows-8, command-line, telnet

I installed telnet by going to

-> Control Panel

-> Turn Windows Features on/off

-> checked "Telnet Client"

Reopened a cmd window. Still the same result:

'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Any thoughts? Windows 8 x64.

Comment: wierd, seems to work for me, granted on windows 8.1. Didn't even need to turn it off and on again

Comment: Yes, however, I can do: Windows Start > type "telnet" > open telnet.exe... Just not from cmd.exe directly.

Comment: Could you do a `set path` in the command prompt and give the result here?

Comment: Small chance you will find the answer over here: http://superuser.com/questions/605335/telnet-wont-run-from-cmd-prompt-in-windows-7

Comment: is `telnet.exe` present in `%windir%\system32`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, but I find that when I launch a cmd window in the normal way telnet works, but when I launch a cmd window from launchy telnet does not work.  This seems to depend on whether I am running a 64 bit cmd.exe or a 32 bit one.

```
dir C:\windows\system32\telnet.exe
```

is found when I and in the standard cmd window but not the launchy cmd window.

The standard cmd window is running dir C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe.  The launch cmd window is running c:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe; even though it launched a shortcut that explicitly asked for C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe

I have solved it for now with a cmd shortcut explicitly calling

```
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-commandprompt_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16384_none_7bcb26c7ee538fe3\cmd.exe
```

but that may well fail if I get updates so the 'real' 64 bit cmd.exe moves.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing telnet client from the command line:

```
pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient"
```

Works for Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista and for newer.

<sup>See: [Install Telnet Client](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275(v=ws.10).aspx).</sup>