# How to pass commands to a telnet window with a batch script?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, telnet

I'm trying to control a wifi device with a batch script using the telnet command in Windows 7, but I don't know how to pass the commands to the telnet window. This will be a part of a longer script tweaking other devices and PC settings.

I can do this manually by running `telnet <IP address> 55443` in cmd.exe, which creates a new window. In that window, I can write the commands for the device and it works as intended. However, when I write the code in the script, like this:

`telnet <IP address> 55443
<device commands>`

The `<device commands>` are not passed on to the newly created telnet window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

---

[image]

---

**The telnet command** does not offer many options for entering some commands...

---

I will leave here two **possible options**

- To do it in **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** with **[vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs)**
- To do it with the software console called **[Telnet Script Tool](https://www.freewareweb.com/cgi-bin/archive.cgi?ID=645)**

> - **`Option #1` using [bat](/questions/tagged/bat) and [vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs)**...

One option would be to use **[SendKey/VBS](https://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html)** very useful for **sending keys, commands etc.,** will send your **entries/type** send them to **telnet** interfaces instance/session...

Below an example of using **[SendKey/VBS](https://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html)** to send login/input data by **bat** file and which **generates in runtime** the file **VBS** to **perform** this **task**.

```bat
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

echo/ && cls && color 9F
%__APPDIR__%mode.com 77,30

set "_user_=cisco_user"
set "_pwd_=my_secret_pwd"
set "_temp_vbs=%tmp%\_tmp_file_vbs_.vbs"

>"!_temp_vbs!"^
    (
     echo/ Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
     echo/ Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
     echo/ StrPwd  = "!_pwd_!"
     echo/ StrUser = "!_user_!"
     echo/ for i=1 To Len^(StrUser^)
     echo/     x = Mid^(StrUser,i,1^)
     echo/     WshShell.SendKeys x
     echo/     Wscript.Sleep 250
     echo/ Next
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 500
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({ENTER})"
     echo/ for j=1 To Len^(StrPwd^)
     echo/     x = Mid^(StrPwd,j,1^)
     echo/     WshShell.SendKeys x
     echo/     Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ Next 
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "dir"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({ENTER})"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "quit"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({ENTER})"
     ) && %__APPDIR__%telnet.exe 192.168.0.254 
     
"%__APPDIR__%cScript.exe" //nologo "!_temp_vbs!"
2>nul >nul del /q /f "!_temp_vbs!" & endlocal & goto :EOF
```

> You can consider seeing this **[question](https://superuser.com/questions/605335/telnet-wont-run-from-cmd-prompt-in-windows-7)**, as to why **`telnet.exe`** is not running on **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**.

To correct this, apply this command on the command line (this requires administrator rights) and run this command only once

```bat
for /f %i in ('%__APPDIR__%where /r "C:\Windows\System32" "telnet.exe.mui" ^|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe [a-z]\-[A-Z] ')do for %C in ("%windir%\system32\.","%windir%\SysWOW64\.")do if exist "%~C." copy /y "%~i" "%~C"
```

---

> - **`Option #2` using [Telnet Script Tool](https://www.freewareweb.com/cgi-bin/archive.cgi?ID=645)**...

*Telnet Scripting Tool is a utility to automate telnet sessions (like calling dip on a Linux system, or doing router maintenance for example).*

The **[Telnet Script Tool](https://www.freewareweb.com/cgi-bin/archive.cgi?ID=645)** can also send entries to telnet...

Basically, this software reads the screen and looks for a prediction string that you will inform for waiting until the next command to be sent to telnet by the software...

Below is an example of using the **Telnet Script Tool** that **send command inputs** by using **content** of a **text file**: **["%temp%\script_ts.scr"](https://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html)**

```bat
@echo off 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

%__APPDIR__%mode.com 77,30
echo/ && color 9F && echo/

set "_user_=my_user_name"
set "_pwd_=my_secret_pwd"
set "_ip_door_=10.0.50.1 23"

>"%temp%\script_ts.scr" ^
    (
     echo=!_ip_door_!
     echo=WAIT "User Name"
     echo=SEND "!_user_!\m"
     echo=WAIT "Passoword"
     echo=SEND "!_pwd_!\m"
    ) && "%temp%\TST10.exe" /r:"%temp%\script_ts.scr" /o:"%temp%\output_ts.txt"
endlocal & goto :EOF
```

---

---

> - Update v2 - Porting bat with sendkey to your command (string):

```bat
 {"id":0,"method":"set_power","params":["on","smooth",500]}
```

To use **`Send Key`** in your command with many special characters, you need to escape **`{:)}`**

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

echo/ && cls && color 9F && %__APPDIR__%mode.com 77,30 && set "_temp_vbs=%tmp%\_tmp_file_vbs_.vbs" && >"!_temp_vbs!"^
  (    
   echo= On Error Resume Next
   echo= Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
   echo= Set ObjShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
   echo= Wsh.sleep 2000 'adjust this timeout for your needs
   echo= ObjShell.AppActivate "MS Telnet CMD" 
   echo= Wsh.sleep 333
   echo= WshShell.SendKeys "o 192.168.0.1 55443~"
   echo= Wsh.sleep 1500
   echo= WshShell.SendKeys "({{}{""}id{""}:0,{""}method{""}:{""}set_power{""},{""}params{""}{:}{[}{""}on{""},{""}smooth{""},500{]}{}}})"
   echo= Wsh.sleep 50
   echo= WshShell.SendKeys "~"
   echo= Wsh.sleep 50
   echo= WshShell.SendKeys "^]"
   echo= Wsh.sleep 50
   echo= WshShell.SendKeys "quit~"
  ) && pushd %windir%\system32\ & title <nul && title MS Telnet CMD

start "" /b "%__APPDIR__%cScript.exe" //nologo "!_temp_vbs!" && call telnet.exe 

:loop
tasklist.exe /nh | findstr.exe /i cscript.exe >nul && goto :loop
2>nul >nul del /q /f "!_temp_vbs!" & popd & endlocal & exit
```

- **[Telnet Script Tool](https://www.freewareweb.com/cgi-bin/archive.cgi?ID=645)**
- **[Telnet Script Tool - Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29201716/telnet-session-with-batch-file/29234144#29234144)**
- **[SendKey and the Escaping for Special Characters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement)**